# Strange behavior with Redux action and reducer when creating action to change keys in state

Tags: reactjs, redux

My apologies for the title.

Anyway, I'm seeing strange behavior in my Redux Dev Tool when I create a certain type of action. The only way to show what I mean is via an example.

Let's say I have a state with this structure:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
isFile: false,
isUploaded: false,
isUser: true
};
```

Since there are simply keys with no nested objects inside the state, I figure I can just create one action to change all of the keys instead of a different action for each particular key.

So the reducer becomes:

```
const CHANGE_KEY = "CHANGE_KEY";

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_KEY:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const changeKeyInState = (key, value) => ({ type: CHANGE_KEY, payload: { key, value } });
```

Now all of this works. So I can call one action to change simple key-value pairs in the state. However, let's say I have different reducers that handle different areas of the state with their own key changing action. When I look at Redux Dev tools, it shows keys added to states that shouldn't be there, which doesn't make sense. For example, if I had a reducer for a logon that has an action that changes `isLoggedIn` key, that key is also added to the above reducer, which doesn't make any sense.

Here is the code for the different reducer:

```
const CHANGE_LOGIN_KEY = "CHANGE_LOGIN_KEY";

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_LOGIN_KEY:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const changeKeyInLoginState = (key, value) => ({ type: CHANGE_LOGIN_KEY, payload: { key, value } });
```

I only see this in Redux Dev tools. I don't know what's going on. Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Is the value of your other types in different reducers also `CHANGE_KEY`?

Comment: @Sasha No. I thought that was the issue too but the keys are different. The behavior still persists.

Comment: Can you share the code for a different reducer so we can see what the issue might be?

Comment: I cannot test it now but different reducers are combined into one after passing through `combineReducer`.. I guess `Redux Dev tools` show all states?

Comment: @Sasha added code for other reducer.

Comment: @Andus makes sense, since it's only visible in Redux tools.

Comment: I think andus might be right. If you're using `combineReducer` then all your states will become one state unless you seperate them by key